# How to stop spinning rocket in space

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

I have been playing KSP for a long time now but I haven't encountered this problem before. I have a rocket I sent to Duna and back, but after timewarping outside of Kerbin's sphere of influence, the rocket was spinning. It won't stop spinning, even with stability assist and rcs. I have plenty of rcs fuel and the rcs thrusters are definitely powerful enough to control it, however it seems like the kraken doesn't want it to stop. Does anyone know of any way to stop the rotation?
Also I have a large list of mods installed that might be causing an issue, but there's too many to list here.

Edit: I was able to stop the rotation with a quicksave, but I noticed a robotics part was clipped into a different place than it had been before the quicksave. Does anyone know the cause behind this bug?

Comment: Some questions to help diagnose the issue: 1) Are you using any mods? 2) Does timewarping stop the rotation, and does it start again after you end timewarp? If yes, does it start immediately at the same speed as before, or accelerate gradually? 3) Does toggling time warp change the orbit of your vessel? In particular, do the apoapsis and periapsis altitudes change (even slightly)?

Comment: I have a long list of mods, most of them adding parts to the game. Timewarping stops the rotation, but it starts again once you drop out of timewarp. I have noticed that my periapsis does change slightly every time I timewarp, but that has happened a before without the spinning issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what the actual cause is, but I suspect you've somehow managed to get your vessel into a glitched state where the parts are exerting an unbalanced (and thus unphysical) acceleration and/or torque on each other.

(You might be able to tell whether it's a pure torque or an off-center acceleration by seeing whether your orbit changes as the vessel starts to spin.  Of course, once it's spinning fast enough, any further net acceleration will tend to cancel out over the course of the rotation.)

Some potential triggers for such bugs that I've seen include:

- Overuse of autostruts (and possibly other factors, especially with large and complex vessels) can sometimes create glitched internal stresses that may cause your vessel to spin and/or shake itself apart.  This is often referred to as a "kraken attack" by KSP players, although that term is also used for other game glitches.

  (Note that, even if you don't deliberately use autostruts on your vessel, some parts like wheels and landing gears are always autostrutted to the heaviest part on your vessel and can thus trigger autostrut-related glitches.)
- Robotic or otherwise movable parts (like wheels, landing gears, cargo bays, etc.) with same-vessel interactions enabled and pushing against other parts on the same vessel can sometimes exert forces without a matching counterforce, creating a non-zero net force on the vessel.  This can and has been exploited to create reactionless "kraken drive" mechanisms that can allow a vessel to reach unlimited velocities without using any fuel, or do other silly things like drive up vertical walls.
- As a specific case of the above, pairs of nearby docking ports with unequal docking force can create an unbalanced force, apparently even without same-vessel interactions.  When used as a deliberate exploit to create reactionless thrust, this is often called a "Zompi drive" or a "Z-drive".

In particular, your observation that quicksaving and loading stopped the torque, but caused some of your parts to move, is consistent with (but not necessarily proof of) a kraken attack caused by unbalanced internal stresses.  Part connections permanently stretching under sufficient stress is, as far as I know, a deliberate feature of the physics engine, and can sometimes relieve the stress by allowing the vessel to inelastically deform.  But if the stress is caused by the physics engine glitching out, it's unlikely to be sufficient.  However, when you reload your vessel, the game will recalculate things like autostruts, and if the vessel was sufficiently deformed, its new configuration may no longer trigger the glitch.